# Slice numpy array using a sparse matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy

Say I have a sparse matrix `c` and a numpy array `a`. I'd like to slice the entries of `a` based on some condition on `c`.

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,0,0,1])
y = np.array([0,0,0,1])
c = sps.csc_matrix( (np.ones((4,)) , (x,y)), shape = (2,2),dtype=int)
a = np.array([ [1,2],[3,3]])
idx = c != 0
```

The variable `idx` is now a sparse matrix of booleans (it only lists True's). I would like to slice the matrix `a` and call the same entries of `a` where `c != 0`.

```
c[idx]
```

works fine but the following will not work:

```
a[idx]
```

I could use `idx.todense()`, but I am finding that these `.todense()` functions are taking up too memory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could index `a` by getting the indices of the rows and cols where `c` is nonzero.  You can do that by converting `c` to the COO matrix and using the `row` and `col` attributes.

Here's some data for an example:

```
In [41]: a
Out[41]: 
array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21],
       [22, 23, 24, 25]])

In [42]: c
Out[42]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [43]: c.A
Out[43]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Convert `c` to COO format:

```
In [45]: c2 = c.tocoo()

In [46]: c2
Out[46]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [47]: c2.row
Out[47]: array([2, 0, 2, 3], dtype=int32)

In [48]: c2.col
Out[48]: array([0, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Now index `a` with `c2.row` and `c2.col` to get the values from `a` at the positions where `c` is nonzero:

```
In [49]: a[c2.row, c2.col]
Out[49]: array([18, 12, 20, 25])
```

Note, however, that the order of the values is not the same as `a[idx.A]`:

```
In [50]: a[(c != 0).A]
Out[50]: array([12, 18, 20, 25])
```

---

By the way, this type of indexing of `a` is not "slicing".  Slicing refers to indexing `a` with a "slice", created using the slice notation `start:stop:step` (or, less commonly, with a builtin slice object `slice(start, stop, step)`), e.g. `a[1:3, :2]`.  What you are doing is sometimes called "advanced" indexing (e.g. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).